# What Time Complexity Does Haskell's "tail"-Function Have?

Tags: haskell

I was reading a tutorial on Haskell when I thought to myself; **what time complexity does Haskell's `tail` function have (and why)?** (I cannot find an answer in any documentation)

I would guess that for a list of size n, the `tail` function would be **O(n)**, i.e just copying over the tail to a new list and returning that one. But then again, I do not know too much about the underlying architecture of Haskell (I'm new to the language).

Of course, I could time it. But I don't know how to time stuff in Haskell yet, and I also want to learn how Haskell handles the problem, to justify why it is O(n)/O(1) or whatever.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Haskell the language doesn't specify. But in GHC (the most frequently used implementation), it is O(1). The tail does not need to be copied -- it is safe to share between the original list and whoever uses just the tail of the list -- because everything in Haskell is immutable.

Challenge problem: why does `init`, which keeps all but the *last* element of a list, run in O(n)? Why doesn't the sharing argument above apply there?

Comment: As for the challenge problem; if I can assume that the list is a singly-linked list (as stated in Williems answer), it should be O(n) because there is no way of having a list without the last element without either removing the "pointer" to the last element (not possible) or copying over the values to a new linked list which does not contain the last element. Is this a correct way to reason?

Comment: @SimonSirak but consider `data NList a = NList ([a], Int)` where `Int` is the list's length. `init` then simply becomes `second (subtract 1)`, more or less.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: if the list is already constructed up to that node, ***O(1)***.

A list in Haskell is a **linked list**. It is defined as:

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

So that means that either we have the empty list, or the `a : [a]` construct. So a *node* with a `head` (the `a`) that refers to an object of type `a`, and a `tail` that refers to a list `[a]` (which can be the empty list, or another node).

The source code of the `tail` in [`base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#tail) is defined as:

> ```
> tail                    :: [a] -> [a]
> tail (_:xs)             =  xs
> tail []                 =  errorEmptyList "tail"
> ```

It runs in O(1) since we simply follow the pointer to the "tail" of that node.

Mind however that **Haskell works lazily**. It is not because we get an object of type `[a]` that we have a *materialized* list: usually Haskell will first have to evaluate the *expression tree* it has been given up to the given node. This can result in evaluating a complex and time consuming algorithm. So it **depends on the expression tree you have been given**.

Comment: I had no idea it was actually a linked list! Thank you for the very useful information :) The accepted answer combined with this one makes for a wholesome answer!