# Triangularizing a list in Haskell

Tags: list, algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

I'm interested in writing an efficient Haskell function `triangularize :: [a] -> [[a]]` that takes a (perhaps infinite) list and "triangularizes" it into a list of lists. For example, `triangularize [1..19]` should return

```
[[1,  3,  6,  10, 15]
,[2,  5,  9,  14]
,[4,  8,  13, 19]
,[7,  12, 18]
,[11, 17]
,[16]]
```

By efficient, I mean that I want it to run in `O(n)` time where `n` is the length of the list.

---

Note that this is quite easy to do in a language like Python, because appending to the end of a list (array) is a constant time operation. A very imperative Python function which accomplishes this is:

```
def triangularize(elements):
    row_index = 0
    column_index = 0
    diagonal_array = []
    for a in elements:
        if row_index == len(diagonal_array):
            diagonal_array.append([a])
        else:
            diagonal_array[row_index].append(a)
        if row_index == 0:
            (row_index, column_index) = (column_index + 1, 0)
        else:
            row_index -= 1
            column_index += 1
    return diagonal_array
```

---

This came up because I have been using Haskell to write some "tabl" sequences in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) (OEIS), and I want to be able to transform an ordinary (1-dimensional) sequence into a (2-dimensional) sequence of sequences in exactly this way.

Perhaps there's some clever (or not-so-clever) way to `foldr` over the input list, but I haven't been able to sort it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all the diagonals of a matrix in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465776/getting-all-the-diagonals-of-a-matrix-in-haskell)

Comment: @MikaelF I don't think so. In particular, that assumes that for input you have a matrix, not a (potentially infinite) list.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I see, you're right.

Comment: More idiomatic than `foldr` you  may do like `unfoldr (Just . combWith comb)` for infinite lists. Alas as i have mentioned under my answer `combWith` is O(n) thus accepted answer using `splitAt` is significantly more efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make increasing size chunks:

```
chunks :: [a] -> [[a]]
chunks = go 0 where
    go n [] = []
    go n as = b : go (n+1) e where (b,e) = splitAt n as
```

Then just transpose twice:

```
diagonalize :: [a] -> [[a]]
diagonalize = transpose . transpose . chunks
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> diagonalize [1..19]
[[1,3,6,10,15],[2,5,9,14],[4,8,13,19],[7,12,18],[11,17],[16]]
```

Comment: Hm. Well, it occurs to me that I'm not super confident `transpose` is O(n). I'm also not super confident it's not -- its implementation is sort of complicated!

Comment: Do you think a variant of this could work on infinite lists? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: This is spiritually what I'm going for in any case—thanks!

Comment: @MikaelF, this appears to work just fine on infinite lists.

Comment: @PeterKagey `take 10 $ diagonalize [1..]` doesn't seem so lazy... edit: I realized that I just confused "being lazy" with "working on infinite lists", but unless an endless loop is an option, in this case I think they're pretty much the same.

Comment: @MikaelF Looks right to me...? `take 3 . map (take 3) . diagonalize $ [1..]` gives `[[1,3,6],[2,5,9],[4,8,13]]`, which seems fine.

Comment: That's because the first list in the list is itself infinite. `take 10 $ map (take 10) $ diagonalize [1..]` indeed gives the first ten elements of the first ten rows.

Comment: Can you do this more efficiently by breaking up into reversed chunks?

Comment: @MikaelF How long should the first chunk of the diagonalized infinite list be?

Comment: @Davislor As PeterKagey pointed out, it's infinite, that's what tripped me up.

Comment: @MikaelF Right. I’m sure you can see how to diagonlize `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],...]`, and otherwise, I’m not sure what operation you mean.

Comment: @Davislor I was initially under the impression that `diagonalize` could account for how many lists you took. For example, the first list of `take 5 $ superLazy [1..]` could just be 5 long, and the function could return straight away. But now I realize that this would mean that `((!! 5) . take 5 . superLazy $ [1..]) /= ((!! 5) . take 6 . superLazy $ [1..])`, and therefore it can't be lazy in that way.

Comment: This solution is fantastic.  I built a solution using a lazy trie of integers and it pales in comparison to this, performance wise.  Empirical measurements indicate that this is very close to linear time, also.  I don't understand how...

Comment: Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044296/4543207) of your's i can see why `tail` is O(1) and `init` is O(n). What i can not understand is why `splitAt` is seemingly not O(n) in this code. Does `right` in `(left, right)` possibly being O(1) have an effect on O(nlogn) overall performance of this code.?

Comment: @Redu `splitAt` is O(n) in this code, but here `n` is the first argument to `splitAt`, not the length of the second list argument. All told, when running `chunk as`, the sum of all the `n`s we pass to `splitAt` is the length of `as`, so `chunk as` runs in O(`length as`).

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be directly related to the set theory argument proving that the set of integer pairs are in one-to-one correspondence with the set of integers (*denumerable*). The argument involves a so-called [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

So, out of curiosity, let's see if we can get a `diagonalize` function that way.
Define the infinite list of Cantor pairs recursively in Haskell:

```
auxCantorPairList :: (Integer, Integer) -> [(Integer, Integer)]
auxCantorPairList (x,y) =
    let nextPair = if (x > 0) then (x-1,y+1) else (x+y+1, 0)
    in (x,y) : auxCantorPairList nextPair

cantorPairList :: [(Integer, Integer)]
cantorPairList = auxCantorPairList (0,0)
```

And try that inside ghci:

```
 λ> take 15 cantorPairList
[(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(0,3),(4,0),(3,1),(2,2),(1,3),(0,4)]
 λ>
```

We can number the pairs, and for example extract the *numbers* for those pairs which have a zero x coordinate:

```
 λ> 
 λ> xs = [1..]
 λ> take 5 $ map fst $ filter (\(n,(x,y)) -> (x==0)) $ zip xs cantorPairList
[1,3,6,10,15]
 λ>
```

We recognize this is the top row from the OP's result in the text of the question.
Similarly for the next two rows:

```
 λ> 
 λ> makeRow xs row = map fst $ filter (\(n,(x,y)) -> (x==row)) $ zip xs cantorPairList
 λ> take 5 $ makeRow xs 1
[2,5,9,14,20]
 λ> 
 λ> take 5 $ makeRow xs 2
[4,8,13,19,26]
 λ>
```

From there, we can write our first draft of a `diagonalize` function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines xs = mapM_ (putStrLn . show) xs
 λ> diagonalize xs = takeWhile (not . null) $ map (makeRow xs) [0..]
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines $ diagonalize [1..19]
[1,3,6,10,15]
[2,5,9,14]
[4,8,13,19]
[7,12,18]
[11,17]
[16]
 λ>
```

### EDIT: performance update

For a list of 1 million items, the runtime is 18 sec, and 145 seconds for 4 millions items. As mentioned by Redu, this seems like O(n√n) complexity.

Distributing the pairs among the various target sublists is inefficient, as most filter operations fail.

To improve performance, we can use a Data.Map structure for the target sublists.

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ExplicitForAll       #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

import qualified  Data.List  as  L
import qualified  Data.Map   as  M

type MIL a = M.Map Integer [a]

buildCantorMap :: forall a.  [a] -> MIL a
buildCantorMap xs = 
    let   ts     =  zip xs cantorPairList -- triplets (a,(x,y))
          m0     = (M.fromList [])::MIL a
          redOp m (n,(x,y)) = let  afn as = case as of
                                              Nothing  -> Just [n]
                                              Just jas -> Just (n:jas)
                              in   M.alter afn x m
          m1r = L.foldl' redOp m0 ts
    in
          fmap reverse m1r

diagonalize :: [a] -> [[a]]
diagonalize xs = let  cm = buildCantorMap xs
                 in   map snd $ M.toAscList cm
```

With that second version, performance appears to be much better: 568 msec for the 1 million items list, 2669 msec for the 4 millions item list. So it is close to the O(n*Log(n)) complexity we could have hoped for.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a good idea to craete a `comb` filter.

So what does `comb` filter do..? It's like `splitAt` but instead of splitting at a single index it *sort of* zips the given infinite list with the given comb to separate the items coressponding to `True` and `False` in the comb. Such that;

```
comb :: [Bool]  -- yields [True,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,False,True...]
comb = iterate (False:) [True] >>= id

combWith :: [Bool] -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
combWith _ []          = ([],[])
combWith (c:cs) (x:xs) = let (f,s) = combWith cs xs
                         in if c then (x:f,s) else (f,x:s)

λ> combWith comb [1..19]
([1,3,6,10,15],[2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19])
```

Now all we need to do is to comb our infinite list and take the `fst` as the first row and carry on combing the `snd` with the same `comb`.

Lets do it;

```
diags :: [a] -> [[a]]
diags [] = []
diags xs = let (h,t) = combWith comb xs
           in h : diags t

λ> diags [1..19]
[ [1,3,6,10,15]
, [2,5,9,14]
, [4,8,13,19]
, [7,12,18]
, [11,17]
, [16]
]
```

also seems to be lazy too :)

```
λ> take 5 . map (take 5) $ diags [1..]
[ [1,3,6,10,15]
, [2,5,9,14,20]
, [4,8,13,19,26]
, [7,12,18,25,33]
, [11,17,24,32,41]
]
```

I think the complexity could be like O(n√n) but i can not make sure. Any ideas..?

Comment: my first naïve solution did have O(n√n) complexity as well. Using a Data.Map structure to distribute the results to the target list of lists, there is a large improvement. Details at the end of my answer.

Comment: @jpmarinier In many cases it could be tricky to obtain meaningful performance metrics due to laziness but we can still get some feeling just by `:set +s`. Doing so @Daniel Wagner's accepted answer seems to be running pretty fast with the list type. Could you please check to see how it compares to your's? I was hoping to achieve similar performance but the `combWith` is nowhere as fast as `spilitAt`.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical of using ghci for performance measurements, so I use ghc -O2. As for lazyness, I print the evaluation of (sum $ map length (diagonalize input)), which gives me back the length of the input list. @Daniel Wagner's solution runs about 20% faster than the Cantor map solution, so it's definitely in the O(n*log(n)) camp. So Daniel's qualms about the nonlinearity of `transpose` seem unfounded. On top of that, it seems more lazyness friendly than the Cantor map. Well done !

Comment: @jpmarinier Checking [this answer of @Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044296/4543207) it seems like the `snd` of the `splitAt`'s return value gets obtained in O(1) but the `fst` is still should be O(n). Somehow this reflects down to the overall performance as O(nlogn).

Comment: Yes, having just looked at the recursive definition for [splitAt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#splitAt), it seems that the (drop n xs) part is essentially obtained for free as a side effect of getting (take n xs). So Daniel is right to use `splitAt` instead of calling `drop` and `take` separately.